# Preview fails with core data lookup but works with random value in Swift 5 / Core Data / FetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to make a temporary preview work but am running into an unusual problem. I have a view that passes along the UUID of the list item that is clicked into a subview. The subview uses this item to populate related items. When I send a randomly generated UUID the code works, but obviously nothing populates since that random UUID doesn't correlate to child objects. I wrote a @FetchRequest to pull Core Data and assign a real UUID, which is called as a static function in the preview provider. When I do this, the preview doesn't compile - no error is ever generated. Here is the code:

```
struct ViewList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Item.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.userOrder, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private static var items: FetchedResults<Item>

static func assignUUID() -> UUID {
    var tempID = UUID()
    for item in items {
        tempID = item.id!
    }
    print (tempID)
    return tempID
}

static var previews: some View {
    
    ViewList(listID: UUID())
}
}
```

I replaced ViewList(listID: UUID()) with ViewList(listID: assignUUID()), but that is when the preview fails.

There's got to be a better way to do this. I shouldn't have to call this function at all and instead fetch a single record, then navigate to the item.id of that first record, set it as a value, and use that in the ViewList pull. I've searched THE ENTIRE Internet (really, just SO) and have found code for older versions of Swift, but none of it compiles in Swift 5. I'm at a loss for ideas and next steps with this and would appreciate any hints / advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the frustrating parts of working with Core Data and the lack of clear documentation out there. I figured this out using some hints from this SO Q&A: [How to fill TextField with data from Core Data and update changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232424/how-to-fill-textfield-with-data-from-core-data-and-update-changes)

My errors started with the main view, where I was using NavigationLink incorrectly to call a detail view. I should have been calling the detail view of a Core Data object using:

```
ViewList(item: item)
```

Where item was the individual member of the @FetchRequest object, 'items'. This was iterated through a ForEach loop.

In the detail view, I needed to declare this item as the Core Data entity as follows:

```
var item: Item
```

Where Item is the Core Data entity I created.

I haven't been able to get the preview to work like it is supposed to, but the following code prevents it from crashing:

```
struct ViewList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private static var viewContext

static var previews: some View {

    let sampleItem = Item.init(context: viewContext)
    ViewList(item: sampleItem)
        .environmentObject(Item())
}
}
```

I thought that sampleItem = Item.init would bring up the initial item in the Entity, but clearly that doesn't seem to be working. I'm hoping someone will have an answer to this part of the question. I hope the earlier explanations help others with similar problems - it seems to be a common question on SO.